# what happens if inside my for loop same object gets initialised in all iterations?

Tags: java

Employee and Hobby are two classes present in the program. Inside for loop, Employee and Hobby objects are getting initialised in every iteration, will they point to a new memory location everytime or same location?

```
public void addEmployees(int a, HashMap<Employee,Hobby> hMap)
{
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i =0; i<a ; i++)
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        Hobby hob = new Hobby();
        System.out.println("Enter id of employee:");
        int num = obj.nextInt();
        emp.setEmployeeId(num);

        System.out.println("Enter name of employee:");
        String str = obj1. nextLine();
        emp.setName(str);

        hob.enterHobby();
        hMap.put(emp,hob);
    }    
}
```

Comment: "new objects are created on the heap every time. they may or may not point to the same location." comment by user Andy

Answer (score 1):

The actual memory location is irrelevant since it's not visible to a Java program, but a new object will be constructed during each iteration.

Comment: memory location becomes relevant in the case like when i do not override equals function in my above code and insert it into hash map.
If memory locations are different, then and only then i will be able to have multiple entries in the hashmap, not otherwise.

Comment: But it's not the *location* in memory that matters, it's just the fact that you have two distinct objects rather than two references to the same object.  You can reasonably expect that distinct objects are stored at different locations in memory, but that's an implementation detail in the JVM.  All that matters to your program is that the JVM knows they're not the same object.

Comment: Yes and JVM(in absence of any overriden version of equals() function) will consider two objects as equal if they point to same location.             
So that's where the consideration of memory location becomes important to me.

Comment: You're missing the point.  Yes, the JVM *probably* uses an object's memory address to establish its identity, but *that doesn't matter to your program*.  Interface vs. implementation.  Someone could write a JVM that (for whatever reason) stores duplicate copies of objects' data in memory, so a pair of object references could point to different memory addresses but nonetheless refer to the "same object" as determined by Java's `==` operator and the default `equals`.  Your program running on that JVM would be none the wiser, and would still work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

new objects are created on the heap every time. they may or may not point to the same location.

Comment: It doesn't actually follow that they will be given a new address. It's probable but not certain. It's also irrelevant.

Comment: memory location becomes relevant in the case like when i do not override equals function in my above code and insert it into hash map. If memory locations are different, then and only then i will be able to have multiple entries in the hashmap, not otherwise.